# Is there a python decoder that produces VALID json and handles NaNs

Tags: python, json, mongodb, bson

I want to serialize mongoDb's output to actual VALID json in python. I've found several libraries, but none of them seems to both **produce valid json** and **handle incompatible values with null** (undefined would be fine also).

**Example input**:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f3e32c71285f85b46d6fb5"),
    "rate" : Infinity
    "value" : NaN
}
```

**Expected output**:

(tried json.dumps and its allow_nan option, but it throws errors and it doesn't help at all)

```
{
    "_id" : { $oid: "57f3e32c71285f85b46d6fb5" },
    "rate" : null,
    "value" : null
}
```

Anyone knows a way / library to achieve this ?

As an example, Javascript's JSON does this fine:

```
Object {_id: "57f3e32c71285f85b46d6fb5", rate: Infinity, value: NaN}
JSON.stringify(tg)
"{"_id":"57f3e32c71285f85b46d6fb5","rate":null,"value":null}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can always make your own encoder (I stole this one from https://gist.github.com/pauloalem/6244976 )

```
import json


class FloatEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def __init__(self, nan_str="null", **kwargs):
        super(FloatEncoder, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.nan_str = nan_str

    def iterencode(self, o, _one_shot=False):
        """Encode the given object and yield each string
        representation as available.

        For example::

            for chunk in JSONEncoder().iterencode(bigobject):
                mysocket.write(chunk)
        """
        if self.check_circular:
            markers = {}
        else:
            markers = None
        if self.ensure_ascii:
            _encoder = json.encoder.encode_basestring_ascii
        else:
            _encoder = json.encoder.encode_basestring
        # if self.encoding != 'utf-8':
        #     def _encoder(o, _orig_encoder=_encoder, _encoding=self.encoding):
        #         if isinstance(o, str):
        #             o = o.decode(_encoding)
        #         return _orig_encoder(o)

        def floatstr(o, allow_nan=self.allow_nan, _repr=json.encoder.encode_basestring,
                _inf=json.encoder.INFINITY, _neginf=-json.encoder.INFINITY,
                nan_str=self.nan_str):
            # Check for specials.  Note that this type of test is processor
            # and/or platform-specific, so do tests which don't depend on the
            # internals.

            if o != o:
                text = nan_str
            elif o == _inf:
                text = 'Infinity'
            elif o == _neginf:
                text = '-Infinity'
            else:
                return _repr(o)

            if not allow_nan:
                raise ValueError(
                    "Out of range float values are not JSON compliant: " +
                    repr(o))

            return text

        _iterencode = json.encoder._make_iterencode(
                markers, self.default, _encoder, self.indent, floatstr,
                self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
                self.skipkeys, _one_shot)
        return _iterencode(o, 0)


d = {"i_will_byte_you_in_the_ass": float("NaN")}
print( json.dumps(d, cls=FloatEncoder) )
```

Comment: Thanks, I could work my problem (using mongoDb) by importing `from bson.json_util import _json_convert, DEFAULT_JSON_OPTIONS` and running
`preserialized = _json_convert(from_bson_object, DEFAULT_JSON_OPTIONS)` before feeding to your FloatEncoder: `print( json.dumps(preserialized, cls=FloatEncoder) )`

Comment: Post note: This is incomplete: this produces `Infinity` and `-Infinity` values. I've replaced them with just `nan_str` (null) and then it's good to go.